# In Nginx, how to detect url and set new parameters for script timeout

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am syncing products to ebay from a cron job and the script keeps timing out  with upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

Using $request_uri to match the url to extend the timeout.  For this example, the exact url is '/index.php?param1=foo&param2=bar'

```
if($request_uri = '/index.php?param1=foo&param2=bar' ){
    fastcgi_read_timeout 540;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3000s;
    proxy_send_timeout   3000;
    proxy_read_timeout   3000;
}
```

I have this in a block just above
`location ~ .php$ {    ... }`

The script runs as expected but seems to have no effect.

I can find a gazillion examples to do redirects, but no examples anywhere on how to change the script timeouts.

My question is, in Nginx, how do you change timeout parameters based upon a specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses a map for each parameter.
The parameter names have to be hard coded,
but at least the order doesn't matter.
These maps could be preprocessed into an include file.

```
map $args $param1 {
    ~(?:\b|&)param1=(?<val>[^\b&]+) $val;
}

map $args $param2 {
    ~(?:\b|&)param2=(?<val>[^\b&]+) $val;
}
```

Then use variables from the param maps to decide the `fastcgi_read_timeout` value.
For this example, if both params have values, bump up the read timeout:

```
map $param1:$param2 $cgi_read_to {
    default 60;
    ~.+:.+ 540;
}
```

Or check for specific parameter values:

```
map $param1:$param2 $cgi_read_to {
    default 60;
    ~^foo:bar$ 540;
}
```

Then use the timeout variable:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout $cgi_read_to;
proxy_connect_timeout 3000s;
proxy_send_timeout   3000;
proxy_read_timeout   3000;
```

Maps tested with nginx/1.23.3.